# Reactor - Utilizar orElse após um filter

Tags: java

Com o seguinte código:

```
public void deleteOrSave() {
    Mono.just("someName")
        .filter(this::isMyName)
        .flatMap(this::delete)
        .orElse(this::save);
}


private boolean isMyName(String name) {
    return false;
}

private Mono<Void> delete(String name) {
    return Mono.empty();
}

private Mono<Void> save(String name) {
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Esse orElse não é possível (nem orElseGet), mas eu gostaria de implementar algo parecido. Onde eu tenho um Mono, filtro e caso for true, chamo um método, caso não, chamo outro. Isso é possível ?

Answer (score 0):

Tem o método `switchIfEmpty` que faz isso.

```
Mono.just("someName")
         .filter(this::isMyName)
         .flatMap(this::delete)
         .switchIfEmpty(save("otherName"));
```